# How to detect image blurring in Python without using OpenCV

Tags: python, algorithm, image, blur

I want to detect whether an image is blurred or not without using OpenCV. Is there any simple algorithm to detect the probability of image blurring?

Most source code uses OpenCV. I want to know other libraries or methods besides OpenCV.

Comment: I think you need to test each pixel against its neighbours and see the difference in color (I'd use YUV or LAB spaces better than RGB). Big difference means a sharp zone, while similar colors means blurry.

Comment: on pixel level blur is often indistinguishable from smooth gradient unless further info is added ... for example if you know where sharp edges should be, or you know there should be no smooth gradient , ... or you can change the focusing, or you have few frames in motion... also what kind of blur are we talking about? lens focus, motion blur, chromatic error?  other? have you any images? you know any DIP/CV questions without input sample are usually meaningless